# Printing a Calendar from Given Month/Year

Tags: java, calendar

I'm working on a Java assignment and it involves printing a calendar after the user specifies a month and a year. I cannot use the Calendar or GregorianCalendar classes. My problem is that the calendar does not correctly print months with their first day on a Saturday. I've looked at my code for about an hour now, and I'm not sure what went wrong. I'm using Zeller's Congruence to find the first day of the month, which is represented by "h".

For example, the calendar on March 2008 (incorrectly) looks like this:

```
     March 2008
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa
 1 
 2  3  4  5  6  7  8 
 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 
23 24 25 26 27 28 29 
30 31
```

Here is my code:

```
package calendar;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calendar
{
    private static int numDays = 0;
    private static int h = 0;
    public static boolean leap(int year)
    {
        if(((year % 4 == 0) && !(year % 100 == 0)) || (year % 400 == 0))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    public static void firstDayOfYear(int year)
    {
        int month = 13;
        year--;
        h = (1 + (int)(((month + 1) * 26) / 10.0) + year + (int)(year / 4.0) + 6 * (int)(year / 100.0) + (int)(year / 400.0)) % 7;
        String dayName = "";
        switch(h)
        {
            case 0: dayName = "Saturday"; break;
            case 1: dayName = "Sunday"; break;
            case 2: dayName = "Monday"; break;
            case 3: dayName = "Tuesday"; break;
            case 4: dayName = "Wednesday"; break;
            case 5: dayName = "Thursday"; break;
            default: dayName = "Friday"; break;
        }
        System.out.println("The first day of the year is " + dayName);
    }
    public static void firstDayOfMonth(int month, int year)
    {
        if(month == 1 || month == 2)
        {
            month += 12;
            year--;
        }
        h = (1 + (int)(((month + 1) * 26) / 10.0) + year + (int)(year / 4.0) + 6 * (int)(year / 100.0) + (int)(year / 400.0)) % 7;
        String dayName = "";
        switch(h)
        {
            case 0: dayName = "Saturday"; break;
            case 1: dayName = "Sunday"; break;
            case 2: dayName = "Monday"; break;
            case 3: dayName = "Tuesday"; break;
            case 4: dayName = "Wednesday"; break;
            case 5: dayName = "Thursday"; break;
            default: dayName = "Friday"; break;
        }
        System.out.println("The first day of the month is " + dayName);
    }
    public static void numDaysInMonth(int month, int year)
    {
        int[] days = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

        if (month == 2 && leap(year)) days[month] = 29;
        numDays = days[month];
        System.out.println("The number of days in the month is " + numDays);
    }
    public static void printCal(int month, int year)
    {
        String[] monthNames = {"","January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};

        System.out.println("    " + monthNames[month] + " " + year);
        System.out.println("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");
        for (int i = 0; i < h - 1; i++)
            System.out.print("   ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i++)
        {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
            if (((i + h - 1) % 7 == 0) || (i == numDays)) System.out.println();
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter month (1-12): ");
        int month = input.nextInt();
        if(month < 1 || month > 12)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid month. Valids inputs are 1-12.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        System.out.print("Enter year: ");
        int year = input.nextInt();
        if(year < 1753)
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid year. Valid inputs are 1753 and beyond.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        if(leap(year))
        {
            System.out.println(year + " is a leap year.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(year + " is NOT a leap year.");
        }
        firstDayOfYear(year);
        firstDayOfMonth(month, year);
        numDaysInMonth(month, year);
        printCal(month, year);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will have the same issue for [every month that starts with a Saturday](http://www.timeanddate.com/calendar/weekday-saturday-1). This means that the problem is probably in this line -

```
for (int i = 0; i < h - 1; i++)
  System.out.print("   ");
```

Having `h` as 7 instead of 0 here will fix it for you. You can either fix that here or you may need to start `h` from 1 to 7 instead of 0 to 6 and make other required changes of course.

Comment: Also, this: `case 0: dayName = "Saturday"; break;`

Comment: Thanks, I know what to do from here.

Comment: It might be painful to change this code, but make sure in the future that you 0 index instead of 1 index. It will make your life a lot easier when accessing arrays and avoiding off-by-1 errors like you got here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your indexes are messed up. What that means is that you are starting your months and days of the weak from 1 instead of 0. However here

```
h = (1 + (int)(((month + 1) * 26) / 10.0) + year + (int)(year / 4.0) + 6 * (int)(year / 100.0) + (int)(year / 400.0)) % 7
```

the %7 at the end makes it start at 0! This causes the loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < h - 1; i++)
  System.out.print("   ");
```

to be

```
for (int i = 0; i < -1; i++)
  System.out.print("   ");
```

since h is 0 for Saturday.

To fix this issue, you should start **all** indexes in your functions with 0. Then when you get user input indexed at 1, simply subtract 1 and pass it into your functions. Then you also won't have that blank entry in front of all your arrays (which by the way should be static finals at the top of the class).

Answer (score 1):

I Know you got the answer. But here is quick fix (Sorry its kinda hacky) that you can incorporate to correct your indexes for Saturday without making many changes to your code.

```
System.out.println("Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa");
        int xx = h == 0 ? 7 : h; // Correct the index for Saturday.
        for (int i = xx; i > 1; i--) // Reversing the loop condition
            System.out.print("   ");
        for (int i = 1; i <= numDays; i++) {
            System.out.printf("%2d ", i);
            if (((i + h - 1) % 7 == 0) || (i == numDays))
                System.out.println();
        }
```

Comment: This works very well and is better than the fix I had in mind. I'd +1 this if I could, but I'm new here.

Comment: Yeah hacks are always better for quick fix, but I will suggest not to go this way. The answer given by @Swapnil is very correct and you should follow his advice.

Answer (score 0):

This will fix the leap year issue

```
if ((((i + h) % 7 == 0) || (i == numDays) && leap(year)))
```