# Menu Based Calendar System

Tags: java, date, menu, calendar

In class I've been tasked with creating a menu based calendar system that will accept user input (they specify a date). They specify the Year, Month, Date (e.g 26) and day of week by entering numbers. I am not allowed to use and date based libraries or built in classes.

Based on this, the program will need to output a calendar based on their input, similar to:

```
Calendar for September 2016
Su  Mo  Tu  We  Th  Fr  Sa
-   -   -   -   1   2   3   
4   5   6   7   8   9   10  
11  12  13  14  15  16  17  
18  19  20  21  22  23  24  
25  26  27  28  29  30  -
```

If the month has 28 days, any day after that day should show as a hyphen ( - ), and if the 1st of the month is a Monday, the Sunday before that should show as a hyphen and not a negative number. I have an array containing the max days for each month which can be used here.

I am not sure how to output the calendar formatted like this, as it needs to start at the date the user defined and work back to the start of the month and forwards to the end of the month.

Any help on how to go about formatting the calendar like in the above example would be appreciated.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070823/printing-a-calendar-from-given-month-year) which is somewhat similar, but it does not take into account the user has chosen what day of the week it is. So the main problem I'm having is getting the calendar to align the date with the day of the week.
update:
I have all the data validation for logic of the calendar (I think). It is:

```
 // Inputs user's choice for year
                System.out.print("Enter Year after 1999:" + " ");
                year = input.nextInt();

                // Data validation to ensure year is later than 1999
                if (year <= 1999) {
                    while (year <= 1999) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a year after 1999: ");
                        year = input.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                // Checking if year is a leap year
                if (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 || year % 400 == 0 && year % 100 ==0) {

                    // Changes Number of Days in February
                    monthdays[1] = 29;
                    leapyear     = true;
                } else {

                    // Changes Number of Days in February
                    monthdays[1] = 28;
                }

                // Inputs user's choice for month
                System.out.print("Enter Month (1 to 12):" + " ");
                month = input.nextInt();

                // Data validation to ensure selected month is between 1 and 12
                if ((month > 12) || (month < 1)) {
                    while ((month > 12) || (month < 1)) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a month between 1 and 12: ");
                        month = input.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                // Inputs user's choice for day
                System.out.print("Enter Day:" + " ");
                day = input.nextInt();

                // Data validation to ensure the day is between 1 and the maximum number of days in that month (based on values contained in the array)
                if ((day > monthdays[month - 1]) || (month < 1)) {
                    while ((day > monthdays[month - 1]) || (month < 1)) {
                        System.out.print("Please enter a valid day for your chosen month: ");
                        day = input.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                // Inputs user's choice for day of week
                System.out.print("Enter day of week (1-7):" + " ");
                weekday = input.nextInt();

                // Data validation to ensure the weekday is between 1 and 7
                if ((weekday > 7) || (weekday < 1)) {
                    while ((weekday > 7) || (weekday < 1)) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a day between 1 and 7:" + " ");
                        weekday = input.nextInt();
                    }
                }

                System.out.println("Thank you for your input. You will now be returned to the main menu.");
```

Comment: any code that you have tried so far?

Comment: I've only tried the code from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070823/printing-a-calendar-from-given-month-year[link], but I haven't managed to get it working correctly to align the date and day of week

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as far as the menu, use the java.io scanner. For the logic for the calendar you will need an array of strings for the days of the week(7), an array of strings for the Months of the year (12). Some knowledge you will need to factor in somehow is that there are 30 days in September,  April, June, and November. There are 31 days in January, March, May, July, August, October, and December. As well as 28 days in February , but don't for get the leap years where February has 29 days. Also Y2K may play into the logic as well. Also know that a year that is divisible by 100 is not a leap year except for the years divisible by 400. There may be some other factors but that should be good to get you started.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I think I've got the logic correct now, and I've added it to the main post. 
The main problem I'm having now is knowing how to format the calendar around the user input (since they select the date and day of week). Any ideas?

Comment: Do you mean the alignment in the correct order, I'll take a look at the code you are using and comment with a suggestion.

Comment: It looks like the code you referenced in the duplicate should work for the formatting. What do you mean?  Are you talking about the dashes?

Comment: if you are just change the "   " in printCal to System.out.print(" - "); , if the difference is yours takes a day (ex 26) then , it doesn't matter because the calendar will be the same.

Comment: I don't see how the day of the week would affect it.

Comment: Sorry, I read through the duplicate wrong, I got it working now, after a bit of tweaking - getting the calendar to display was a bit complicated. 
Thanks again.

Comment: no problem, glad to help a bit :)